# Isn't the tag 'fatima-zahra' a synonym of 'fatima'?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

The tag [fatima-zahra](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fatima-zahra) has no current synonyms. Isn't the tag [fatima](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fatima) a synonym as [Zahra](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatimah) **is a title of Fatima** and they are both the same person?

From [Wikipedia page of Fatima](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatimah):

> al-Zahra(The Splendid One/The Lady of Light)

**Question:** Isn't the tag 'fatima-zahra' a synonym of 'fatima'?

---

Current usage:

Tagged [fatima](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fatima) (2 Q's):

- [What was the Meher of Hazrat-Fatimah?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/27942/17163)
- [Why is Laylatul Qadr interpreted to hazrat Fatima?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/16310/17163)

Tagged [fatima-zahra](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fatima-zahra) (8 Q's):

- [Contradictory hadiths on the most beloved individuals to the Holy Prophet in Jami at-Tirmidhi](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/32888/17163)
- [Hadith about the prophet and his daughter fatimah tongue suckling](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/27567/17163)
- [Fadak, Fatima and Abu baker](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/16412/17163)
- [Was Lady Fatimah (a.s.) higher than many other men? (Shia view)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/12532/17163)
- [What is the reason that the burial place of Lady Fatimah (as) still concealed?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/12503/17163)
- [Why is location of Fatima the daughter of Prophet Mohammad not known?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/12138/17163)
- [According to Shi'a Islam, did Fatimah (daughter of Prophet Muhammad) die naturally, or was she killed?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/5988/17163)
- [Do Shi'ites believe in other holy books/revelations after Qur'an?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/2530/17163)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, they're the same. At the very least, the two [fatima](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fatima) questions are definitely referring to [Fatimah bint Muhammad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatimah), aka [fatima-zahra](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fatima-zahra), so they're synonymous in this particular case.

Whether or not there's any *other* Fatimas out there who would warrant tagging and necessitate distinguishing *this* Fatima from them, and whether or not the "Zahra" honorific is the best way *to* distinguish them, I can't say.

---

**Update:** Since it's been over a week with nobody making any arguments to the contrary, I've gone ahead and merged/synonymed [fatima](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fatima)→[fatima-zahra](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fatima-zahra).